# Delay using readline in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function  readFile(){  
  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(FILE_PATH)
  });  
  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("HEYYYYY");     
    }, 10000);    
  });
}
```

Why does this only waits 10 seconds once , and the prints 'hey' ? I want to print hey each 10 seconds but it's not working. No idea why.

Edit: This is going to be repeated by the amount of lines that there are on a file (look at the listener 'line') I need to delay 10s between each line.

Comment: Use `setInterval`, not `setTimeout` if you want it to repeat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: @ChristianSantos No, please, read the edit I just made :)

Comment: Does the input file have multiple lines, ending with end-of-line input (\n, \r, or \r\n) characters? (The last line does not matter, but the lines before should terminate with the above).  - https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line

Comment: @IshanThilinaSomasiri yeah, they do

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it with the "Example: Read File Stream Line-by-Line" found in: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

In your case it would be something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
    const readline = require('readline');

    async function processLineByLine() {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(FILE_PATH);

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
    // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

    for await (const line of rl) {
      // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
      console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
      await sleep(10000)
    }
  }

  function sleep(ms){
        return new Promise(resolve=>{
            setTimeout(resolve,ms)
        })
    }
```

This example would print you a line every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `setTimeout` does not halt execution, so the next line gets processed immediately. It would be easier to iterate the readline interface using a `for await ... of` expression, and in here you can `await` a promise-based timeout function.

Answer (score -1):

It's not waiting 10 seconds once. its just that each line is read so fast, there's almost not difference in the start time. you can add a variable that increase the delay by 10 seconds in each callback so you each line is print each 10 seconds.

```
function  readFile(){  

  var delay = 0;  

  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(FILE_PATH)
  });  
  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

    delay += 10000;    

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("HEYYYYY");     
    }, 10000+delay);    
  });
}
```

Comment: why do you keep adding 10s? I don't understand this. Would you explain a little bit ?

Comment: You will get each line in `lineReader.on('line')` almost at the same time, so if you call `setTimeout` all the timeouts will be at the same time too.  To add a 10 seconds delay between each line you can just add 10 seconds in each line you get to the timeout